# while loop shell script

Tags: linux

I have written a Linux (bash) shell script using while loop and I kept sleep command to execute the script for every 60 sec and the output is redirected to other file. After few hours I stopped the script and it doesn't stop executing and I deleted the script still it is running and the output file is updated every 60 seconds. I could see sleep command in the process running by Linux. I tried to kill the PID of sleep using kill -9 PID command. No use. It is in my production server.can some one help out. How should we stop the execution of script.

Comment: Can you please [edit] with punctuation and paragraphs, and ideally the code in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sleep` command is invoked by your script. If you kill the `sleep` command the script advances to the next command. You need to look at the parent pid (PPID) of the `sleep` command using `ps` for instance. Then look for the corresponding parent pid (PPID) and kill the process that belongs to that PID

```
ps -ef |(head -1; grep sleep)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lambert   4062  4041  0 08:47 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 5

ps -p 4041
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4041 pts/3    00:00:00 myscript.sh

kill 4041
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be running in the background:

```
       $ jobs
       [1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &

       $ kill %1
       [1]+  Terminated              sleep 100
```

You can also use pkill and pgrep

Use killall to stop all of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'ps -ef | grep *your script name*' to find the pid of your task. Then use 'kill -9 *your pid*' to kill the process.